# Form oversize than setting

Tags: c#

My working laptop is 1920 x 1080. C# form size set to the 1920 x 1080 with Top most set as true, and window state set to maximum. A panel was sized to 1850 x 500. Here is the part that puzzled me, the form displayed during debugged was wider than the screen, the panel was wider and the left edge was not displayed. 
This the first time I come across this. Any idea how to resolve this?

One more thing: the Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds value is 1536 x 864
why not 1920 x 1080 ?

Comment: It's not a question about code unless you post the code that isn't operating as expected.    With issues in the Designer, it's also wise to screenshot what you're seeing vs. what you expect.

Comment: How much wider?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13228185/17034

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant is correct.

I checked my dell development notebook (window 10 home), the default and recommended "Change the size of text, apps, and other items:" was set at 125%.

I tried and test the same project files at another desktop ( which has a default setting at 100%).

voila : the normal display like WYSIWYG ! A hard lesson learned. I had to rework all the UI all over again.